# How to calculate the area between 2 contours in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, contour

I have list of contours (reached), the contours are closed and I have to calculate areas between them. I've tried scipy.integrate, but it give me error. I have about 200 contours and have to calculate area for all of them, easy way to do it? Any idea? Thanks!

```
reached = [ contour for contour in prodcontours[prodwell.name] if contour.latest_time_on_contour()<tau ]
area = trapz(reached, dx=well.radius)
```

UPDATE

```
for tau in years :
for contour in reached:
    ctr = np.array(contour)
    area =cv2.contourArea(ctr)

   TypeError: <unknown> data type = 15 is not supported
```

What does it mean?
or 
how to rewrite this one for 200 contours, without entering coordinates for each

```
 contour = numpy.array([[[0,0]], [[10,0]], [[10,10]], [[5,4]]])
 area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
```

**Edit 1:** By the way, my contours are complex numbers, May be problem of that?

**Edit 2:** It was, because of my contours are complex numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could use the OpenCV library.

`area = cv2.contourArea(contour)`

where contour could be a 2D numpy array containing the contour points.

You may read the OpenCV documentation at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html
for more details.

Comment: Perhaps the error is that your ``contour`` is not a numpy array.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: No, with numpy everything is ok.